# Ajax - error on .cshtml call

Tags: c#, ajax, response

i have the next problem:
i'm creating an ajax call to a .cshtml file... in localhost it works fine, but when uploaded on server it throws an error "Forbidden (403)"

this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "~/MyProcessPage.cshtml",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: { id: 1 },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (res) { console.log(res); },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

and this is my C# code:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
{
    var id= Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    Response.Write(id);
}
```

Please notice i'm using razor but NOT using MVC!

Thanks!

Comment: Does this page load for you without AJAX by entering `...\MyProcessPage.cshtml` in browser?

Comment: Well if it works in localhost, the first I would look at is the server configuration, folder permission, permitted files to be requested and responds it could give... It sounds like a configuration issue.

Comment: why crossDomain: true ?

Comment: @serhiyb myprocesspage shows blank, it only response the json

Comment: @derloopkat i tried both, true and false... don't know the difference

Comment: when you get blank page from MyProcessPage.cshtml at server, are you including the id?

Comment: @derloopkat yes i do

Comment: It makes no sense when you say this works locally. This cannot work. You probably are confused because the code does the same in error and success function. This code with ~ symbol is in an external js file, datatype is json and contentType is x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: @derloopkat when success (locally) , console logs my object created in myProcessPage.
... when error(server), console logs an error object with code 403 forbidden

Comment: can i change that cshtml for a service? is it too hard?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shold change the url

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Content("~/MyProcessPage.cshtml")',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: { id: 1 },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (res) { console.log(res); },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: yes, that makes sense, assuming the ajax call is inside another .cshtml file and not into an external .js file.

Comment: i guess that @Url ir for MVC